# Java jar file (JWT token generator) need to import in jmeter and have to generator token by running method and use it in one test step

Tags: jmeter

I have to pass a token in header  generated by jwt generator which is  a jar .
How to import and call the method to use token.
I am using Beanshell sampler and importing the package and class and then in next line calling the method.
But this is not working.

Comment: Show your code and error

Answer (score 0):

1. Place the jwt generator jar (and all its dependencies, if any) to [JMeter classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your test plan, make sure to choose [`groovy`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) as the language and put the code into the "Script" area
4. There is no such a thing as "not working", if JMeter is not capable of executing your custom code it will print the relevant error(s) to [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file